PLINK to VCF seems to to not convert correctly, what am I missing
I have Illumina Infinium Global SNP array data that I want to compare to same sample WES data in VCF format. To do that, I am trying to convert the plink files (.bed, .bim and .fam) into vcf.
I am using the following command:
plink2 --bfile gsa_prefix --fa {input.fa} --ref-from-fa --recode vcf id-paste=iid --out out_prefix

Somewhere I am missing something in the conversion or doing it wrong, it is not going properly. For some homozygous variants, the genotypes are switched, even though I think I tried to add the ref-from-fa to lock the reference to the REF alt, so I would expect this to be translated somehow in the conversion to vcf.
Here some examples (left before the || is the GSA, right after the || is WES):
sample 1: 
chr3    10222796    rs3844283   C   G   .   .   ORIGINAL_CHROM=chr3;ORIGINAL_POS=10264480;ORIGINAL_STRAND=+;AC=2;AN=2   GT  1/1 || chr3 10222796    .   C   <*> 0   .   .   GT:GQ:MIN_DP:PL 0/0:50:17:0,51,509  106

sample2: 
chr3    10222796    rs3844283   C   G   .   .   ORIGINAL_CHROM=chr3;ORIGINAL_POS=10264480;ORIGINAL_STRAND=+;AC=0;AN=2   GT  0/0 || chr3 10222796    .   C   G,<*>   70.9    PASS    .   GT:GQ:DP:AD:VAF:PL  1/1:67:104:0,104,0:1,0:70,70,0,990,990,990  99

So, this is not the case for all positions, some homozygous variants are the same genotype (i.e. 1/1 and 1/1). I know Illumina SNP array has this very elaborate way of annotating their "ALT"/"REF" alleles (or Allele A or B): https://www.illumina.com/documents/products/technotes/technote_topbot.pdf
But likely I am missing something because of this. I do not think this is technical sequencing wise (i.e. array just didn't pick up the SNP or the other way around). The pattern is too obvious over too many positions. And I just do not know now if a 0/0 means no variant/homozygeous ALT in terms of the reference genome or the other way around.
Note: It is a subsample of 22 samples from the plink files, it was subsampled by someone else.
Edit: could it be that my predecessor did not use --keep-allele-order when converting the array data to plink (with plink1.9)? The command that that I found in a random .txt file #ahlawdhelpme:
plink --file GSA_data --keep keep_list_22.txt --allow-no-sex --make-bed --out GSA_22_participants

I will look into this/try to redo this ^ and come with an update.
Edit2: the --keep-allele-order did not correct this.
Hope anyone has any insights. Thanks.
